# Elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p (p^{1/p^\infty})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

How would one describe the field $\mathbb{Q}_p (p^{1/p^\infty})$ in terms of its elements? I know that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ in the non-Archimedean norm $|\cdot|_p$; thus, we can describe the elements in terms of formal power series. But I'm not certain what adjoining $p^{1/p^\infty}$ does to this field. I saw it as an example of a "perfectoid field" in: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5948v1.pdf

Comment: Bonus question: what is the general form of an element of the completion, as a $p$-adic series ?

Comment: You may, and sometimes must, think of $\Bbb Q_p$ as formal power series in $p$, but for now, just think of this field as a complete discretely valued field whose ring of integers has $p$ generating the maximal ideal. And as @TrevorGunn says, any particular element may be expressed as a $\Bbb Q_p$-linear combination of powers of a *particular* $p^{1/p^n}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p^{1/p^{\infty}}$ is shorthand for $p^{1/p},p^{1/p^2},p^{1/p^3},\dots$ So $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{\infty}}) = \bigcup_n \mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^n})$. You might want to also read the AMS survey ["What is a Perfectoid Space?"](http://www.ams.org/notices/201409/rnoti-p1082.pdf)